# How does Windows know where to find Outlook

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, path

I have Outlook installed on my machine.

It is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16 is however not in my system path.

Regardless, when I enter 'Outlook' at the command prompt in the root directory, Outlook starts.

How does Windows know where to find Outlook?

Comment: What do you mean, "the root directory"? Do you open up a command prompt in your user folder (Default if you just type cmd in start)? System32 (default if you type in cmd in start then run as admin)?

Comment: When you installed Outlook via the installer, it probably added itself to path.

Comment: When office is installed, shortcuts are added to your Start Menu. Search in Windows Start screen also parses the Start Menu for searches.Hence Outlook is found by Windows search.

Comment: AppPaths - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx Have a look under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

Comment: by root directory I mean c:\

Comment: For what I needed to do, HelpingHand's answer was what I needed to know - thank you!